# PyQt5 get data from model to show custom widget in QListView

Tags: python, user-interface, model-view-controller, pyqt5

I'm using PyQt5 and trying to create a GUI with a list of some custom data structure (`Recipe`), and I defined a custom widget as a subclass of `QWidget` that describes how it should be displayed. 
I am trying to use MVC so I have a `QListView` and I subclassed `QAbstractListModel`. 
I want the list to contain my custom widget instead of just text, so I also defined an item delegate for it that returns that widget. Perhaps my understanding of exactly how these three components (model, item delegate, view) work together is flawed, because I'm not sure how to access whatever is returned from the `data()` method of the model and turn that into the particular widget I want to display in that list cell.

Example code:

```
class Recipe:
    pass # custom data structure

class RecipeWidget(QWidget, RecipeWidgetUI):
    def __init__(self, recipe, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RecipeWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.recipe = recipe
        self.setupUi(self)
        # some code here to populate the UI elements with data from self.recipe

class RecipeListModel(QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, recipes, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RecipeListModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.recipes = recipes
    def rowCount(self, index):
        return len(self.recipes)
    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return str(self.recipes[index.row()]) # this is the part I'm confused about

class RecipeItemDelegate(QItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        return RecipeWidget(recipe, parent=parent) # where do I get recipe from??

class MainWindow(...):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...
        self.model = RecipeListModel(recipes)
        self.listView.setModel(self.model)
        self.listView.setItemDelegate(RecipeItemDelegate(self.listView))
```

I know the `data(...)` function in the model is supposed to return a string; what I don't understand is:

- How do I instead return my `Recipe` data structure? Do I have to serialize it somehow and then deserialize later?
- Where does `RecipeItemDelegate` see what was returned by the `data(...)` function in order to properly construct the recipe object?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your question. The item data can be accessed using `index.data(role)`, you could either populate the RecipeWidget in createEditor by adding a keyword argument using `index.data()`, or, better, use [`setEditorData()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemdelegate.html#setEditorData).

Comment: Did u find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Each item can hold several data properties based on roles. These data properties are QVariants. You can embed a lot of different things in a QVariant, even custom objects.

I would say it is best practice to use a string for the Display role, and use Qt.UserRole (or Qt.UserRole + n) for other things. Your delegate can still access those by providing that role  when querying the item's data.

I am not versed in how to use custom types for QVariant with PyQt5 though as I develop with C++. Note that if you were to use Qt for Python instead of PyQt5, you would not need to work with QVariant and could just set and get any custom python variable.

Comment: Since PyQt5, QVariants are transparently converted to python or PyQt objects (the same happens in PyQt4 when using SIPv2).

Comment: Changing the return in the `data` function to `return self.recipes[index.row()]` and getting the recipe as `recipe = index.data(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)` in `RecipeItemDelegate` results in blank rows being added to the list. And the `createEditor(...)` function never seems to be called...

Answer (score 0):

1. model.data() needs to provide data for desirable role. in you case, you may decide to use Qt.DisplayRole to represent data for display. You can just `return self.recipes[index.row()]`. but if you want to support drag and drop, QT needs to be able to serialize the data. for now let's just provide python index in the self.recipes, which can be serialized. `return index.row() # which happens to be python index in the self.recipes`
2. RecipeItemDelegate needs to be able to reference to the Recipe object with data from model.data(). So, let's init RecipeItemDelegate(parent, parent.model().recipes)
3. RecipeItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index) shall be implemented to paint the "display". Inside paint(), index.data(Qt.DisplayRole) gets the data - row in the recipes(happens to be index.row()). self.reference_to_recipes[index.data(Qt.DisplayRole)] gets the Recipe object. then you pick up "painter", paint information from data you get, in the "option" specified area and style. see also QItemDelegate::paint in QT documenation.

if you want the delegate to support editing,:

> 1. createEditor() should create the widget used to change data from the model
> 2. setEditorData() should populate the widget with data to manipulate. like `editor.set_recipe(self.reference_to_recipes[index.data(Qt.DisplayRole)])`
> 3. updateEditorGeometry() ensures that the editor is displayed correctly with respect to the item view.
> 4. setModelData() returns updated data to the model. like `model.setData(index, editor.get_modified_recipe(), Qt.EditRole)` of course, model.setData() needs to be able to handle Recipe object upon Qt.EditRole

Comment: I see; so my actual widget drawing logic needs to be implemented in `paint(...)`. Is there a way to easily paint a whole widget? Or does it have to be painted component by component? Most of the examples I see online use `QPainter` to do really low level drawing like a single rectangle at a time.

Comment: check QWidget::render() in the QT Doc.

Comment: I now have a `paint` method inside QItemDelegate with `recipeWidget.render(painter, QtCore.QPoint(option.rect.x(), option.rect.y()), QtGui.QRegion(0, 0, option.rect.width(), option.rect.height()))` but still nothing is being rendered, even though I've made sure that the method is in fact getting called, and `recipeWidget` is set to the right thing each time.

Comment: void QWidget::render(QPaintDevice *target, const QPoint &targetOffset = QPoint(), const QRegion &sourceRegion = QRegion(), QWidget::RenderFlags renderFlags = RenderFlags(DrawWindowBackground | DrawChildren)) ===》The QPaintDevice class is the base class of objects that can be painted on with QPainter. （it is a place you paint on with painter but not painter itself. like you use a pen to draw on paper but not on the pen itself）

Comment: so should I be using `painter.device()` instead of `painter`?

Comment: not sure. you can try it. you may also look into documentation. at the very least, i think you can use qpixmap.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215842/discussion-between-raghav-malik-and-tosimplicity).